# Semitransparent black status bar without toolbar or actionbar

Tags: android, xml, material-design

In my app I want to implement semitransparent black statusbar like in VKontakte Android mobile app. It looks something like this

[statusbar VK app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ntjz.jpg)

What I have now is **values-v21/styles.xml** with this lines of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But what I have as a result is completely transparent statusbar. I'm testing on **Meizu M3E** and this is screenshot of what I have right now

[my app status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCoZn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

then you can set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”
```

http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

https://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/

Comment: do I need statusBarColor set to "#ff000000"? and  what is in your "AppTheme.Base"?

Comment: glad to help you happy coding..:)